# Pass data from one table to another in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm learning mysql and i try to pass data from one table to another.

In Details, i have table1 with columns id, firstname, lastname etc.

Then i have a table2 with columns id, firstname, lastname, bodyfat, bodyweight, matchid.

The thing that i want is to pass the data firstname and lastname from table1 to table2 and they should be matched on table1.id = table2.matchid. Also the procedure should happen every time that new records are inserted into the table1, so the specific values are also updated and displayed in table2.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an after insert trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_user_insert
AFTER INSERT
    ON table1 FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

INSERT INTO table2 (firstname, lastname, matchid)
VALUES
    (NEW.firstname, NEW.lastname, NEW.id);

END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

This assumes that you only want to insert new records in `table2` with the first and last name, which is all the available information in `table1`.  You could include other columns in the insert, but you would have to specify how to do that.

Beyond this, if you needed to initially populate `table2` from `table1`, you could do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (firstname, lastname)
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM table1
-- WHERE <conditions>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details, but i can't still see the data firstname, lastname in table2

Comment: @ath_zach My code is correct and should be working.  Did you actually create a trigger?  It won't act on previous inserts, only inserts on `table1` which occur after you created the trigger.

Comment: Yes i believe it! let me work on that a little bit cause i'm a newbie in mysql!

Comment: all right! the data are displayed in the table2, my mistake was that i run the query in table2, so now it's working! So, i figure that if i want to match the step1.id = table2.match.id i have to use where conditions that you mention?

Comment: @ath_zach Sorry, I neglected to insert `table1.id` into `table2.matchid`.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot! i worked on that and it partly does the thing that i want cause in table2 (which in my real project is called 'man') the data firstname, lastname from table1 (which in real project is 'step1') aren't matched with the ans3, mandate data from table2, but instead auto increament seperates them! is there any way to fix this? please check the photo that i added in my question!

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Edit your question and explain.  _No_ screen captures.

Comment: yes i see that my question is a bit confusing! i'll edit my question!

Comment: You're going to need to show some data here.  I don't see any problem with my answer, at least not with regard to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help! i'll make a new question with more details about my project!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a trigger on table 1. A trigger is a named database object that is associated with a table, and that activates when a particular event occurs for the table. Some uses for triggers are to perform checks of values to be inserted into a table or to perform calculations on values involved in an update.

You can set a trigger on insert event in table 1. Here is a link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html  that shows examples of trigger in mysql. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can Create Trigger on Table1 with the insert or update statement into the Table2 using AFTER keyword, so that whenever a data is inserted in the Table 1 the trigger will be invoked and does the respective action based on your trigger definition.

For more details about how to create and use a trigger for MySQL refer the below link.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html